# Ionic: RegExp .test() function not working in android device

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I write a funtion using .test(string) to let a input only allow number and BackSpace key. When I test in ionic serve or Ios, it worked. But when I test in Android its not working, input field will allow all the character inputed. 
When I use console.log(event), it return the key=Unidentified.

I dont know how to fix this, anyone give me advise, plz!

.ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  isValidNumber(event) {
    return /\d|Backspace/.test(event.key);

  }
}
```

.html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-input  type="text" (keydown)="isValidNumber($event)"></ion-input>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-content>
```

Test in Android version 5.5.1

Comment: what android version that is?

Comment: @Tomas Panik  Android 5.1.1

Comment: hmm I don't know the cause then (Android 5 should have quite up-to-date WebView which should have such fundamental javascript functionality)